# Run double animation on a view model property in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to start a DoubleAnimation on a ViewModel property that is bind to the height of a Grid.

The following example works but used the HeightProperty of the Grid directly.

```
private void _runAnimation(Grid target, double from, double to)
{
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(from, to, new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)));

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(animation);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new System.Windows.PropertyPath(Grid.HeightProperty));

    sb.Begin();
}
```

Is it possible to use a ViewModel Property that is bind to the height of the grid?

My ViewModel property:

```
private double entryHeight = entryHeightDefault;
public double EntryHeight
{
    get
    {
        return entryHeight;
    }
    set
    {
        entryHeight = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Example of binding to height:

```
<Grid x:Name="GdEntry" Height="{Binding Path=EntryHeight}"  Background="Transparent">
```

Why do I need this solution:
I have a ListView that used custom DataTemplates. I tried to animate a grid within the data template. With the SelectionChange event from the listview I get only the selected and unselected view models. I now that I can find out the right ListViewItems and the childs by using the VisualTreeHelper but it would be better to use the view model property.

Comment: The target property of an animation must be a dependency property. IMO, animations do not belong into view models.

Comment: Why would you want to animate the view model property instead of the target property? Animations belong to the view.

Comment: I have edited my comment to answer your question.